# How to query the Search Console API for security issues?

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

the Google Search Console offers [a "Security Issues" section](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044101?hl=en).

How can I query these entries via the Search Console or any other API?

Neither the [Sites:get](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/sites/get?hl=en) nor [the URL inspection](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/urlInspection.index/inspect?hl=en) calls return any security issues items.

The Safe Browsing API doesn't show any of the security issues shown by the Search Console.

Comment: If it isn't in the the API documentation, it isn't like somebody here would be able to answer the question.  Have you asked Google?

Comment: I can easily miss a relevant API or call argument and Stackoverflow is more likely to answer than Google.